# Databinding basics in android studio . ActivitymainBinding is not a subtype of ViewDataBinding

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

[1.I add databinding in android in build.gradle.app
2.I add layout file to the xml code
3.I import the necessary items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFuq9.png)

But I dont know what should i correct in this code . Could any help me with this code ? I am searching for a while .I attached the image file .

Comment: It sometimes doesn't generate the binding class files automatically. Run the build once. Click the build button and see if it works.

Comment: clear project and re build.i will work

Comment: Can you share a sample project?

Answer (score 0):

Close your **Android studio** and delete `.gradle` and `.idea` the folder in your project directory. Then open your project again. It will be worked then hopefully.